# Josephus Survivor

Tags: c#, math, game-theory

So I have the method below:

```
public static int JosSurvivor(int n, int k) 
{
    if (n == 1) 
        return 1; 
    else
        return (JosSurvivor(n - 1, k) + k - 1) % n + 1; //problem on this line
}
```

I'm wondering why this works:

```
   return (JosSurvivor(n - 1, k) + k - 1) % n + 1;
```

And this doesn't:

```
   return (JosSurvivor(n - 1, k) + k) % n;
```

Comment: Because they're not the same thing? The math is different, and therefore so is the result.

Comment: As Ken pointed out, the math is different. It would be much more helpful if we knew what you were trying to achieve with this method. Can you provide context as to how you expect this to perform?

Comment: You should include what the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) is

Comment: The fact that the possible answers are 1 to n that is why it has the +1 at the end because modulo n would only give values from 0 to n-1 (basically it converts from a 0 based answer to a 1 based answer)

Comment: Actually the second one "works" if you pass in a zero based value for k (so instead of 5 you'd pass in 4) and expect a zero based answer.  So basically the -1 is converting the 1 based k value to a zero based value for the calculation and the +1 is turning it back to a 1 based answer at the end.

Comment: Ok, thank you! It saved me from having to create and iterate through an arraylist!